# Scroll function is not able to detect css function for last div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");
        $('a').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('actve');
        })
        $(this).addClass('actve');

        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 2
        }, 500, 'swing', function() {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            var scroll_start = 0;
            var startchange = $('.q-intro-text');
            var offset = startchange.offset();
            // $(document).scroll(function() {
            //     scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
            //     if (scroll_start > offset.top) {
            //         $('#q-nav').css('background-color', 'black');
            //     } else {
            //         $('#q-nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
            //     }
            // });
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event) {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#q-nav a').each(function() {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#q-nav ul li a').removeClass("actve");
            currLink.addClass("actve");
            $('.actve').css('color', '#4d4d4d');
            $('.actve').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #ff363f');
        } else {
            currLink.removeClass("actve");
            currLink.css('color', '#898989');
            currLink.css('border-bottom', '1px solid white');
        }
    });
}
```

```css
 .container {
     padding: 0;
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
 }
 
 .menu {
     display: none;
 }
 
 header {
     display: none;
 }
 
 .carousel-indicators li.active {
     width: 1.3rem;
     height: 1.3rem;
     margin-right: 0.8rem;
 }
 
 .carousel-indicators li {
     width: 1.3rem;
     height: 1.3rem;
     margin-right: 0.8rem;
 }
 
 #myTopnav {
     display: none;
 }
 
 #myTopnav .q-hamburger {
     display: none;
 }
 
 #q-nav {
     width: 100%;
     height: 4rem;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     background-color: white;
     padding-top: 1.5rem;
 }
 
 #q-nav ul {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: flex-end;
 }
 
 #q-nav .q-nav-about {
     position: relative;
     color: #898989;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 0rem 2rem 0 2rem;
 }
 
 #q-nav ul li {
     list-style: none;
 }
 
 #q-nav .q-nav-work {
     position: relative;
     color: #898989;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 0rem 2rem 0 2rem;
 }
 
 #q-nav .q-nav-contact {
     position: relative;       
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 0rem 8rem 0 2rem;
 }
 
 .q-intro-text {
     height: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0; 
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
     display: flex;
 }
 
 .q-intro-text .q-text-header {
     font-size: 2rem;
     font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 .q-intro-text .q-mobile-app-text {
     margin: 0 0 0 10rem;
     color: #ffffff;
 }
 
 #about-us {
     background-color: white;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout {
     height: 30rem;
     background-color: white;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
     padding-top: 2.5rem;
     text-align: center;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-title {
     margin-top: 1rem;
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #448ccb;
 }
 
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images {
     width: 100%;
     height: 50%;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image1 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     flex-direction: column;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image2 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     flex-direction: column;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image3 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     flex-direction: column;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image1 .q-images-text {
     margin-top: 1rem;
     color: #898989;
     font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image2 .q-images-text {
     margin-top: 1rem;
     color: #898989;
     font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image3 .q-images-text {
     margin-top: 1.6rem;
     color: #898989;
     font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image1 .q-images {
     width: 30%;
     height: 30%;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image2 .q-images {
     width: 30%;
     height: 30%;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image3 .q-images {
     width: 30%;
     height: 30%;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image3 #q-code {
     width: 25%;
     height: 25%;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-team {
     height: 39rem;
     width: 100%;
     padding-top: 2rem;
     padding-bottom: 2rem;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
     -webkit-flex-direction: column;
     -ms-flex-direction: column;
     flex-direction: column;
     -webkit-box-align: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
     align-items: center;
     text-align: center;
     background: url("/test/images/ic_team.jpg") no-repeat;
     background-size: contain;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-team .q-team-text {
     font-size: 1.3rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-bottom: 2rem;
     color: white;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-team .q-team-info {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     padding: 0 8rem 3rem 8rem;
     -webkit-box-pack: center;
     -ms-flex-pack: center;
     justify-content: center;
     -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
     -webkit-flex-direction: row;
     -ms-flex-direction: row;
     flex-direction: row;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-team .q-team-info .q-team-info-layout {
     width: 33%;
     height: 100%;
     padding: 2rem 1rem 0 1rem;
     margin: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
     background-color: white;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-team .q-team-info .q-team-info-layout .q-team-images {
     width: 7.2rem;
     height: 7.8rem;
     padding-bottom: 1rem;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-team .q-team-info .q-team-info-layout .q-team-member {
     margin-top: 1rem;
     margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
     color: #ff363f;
 }
 
 #work {
     width: 100vw;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
     -webkit-flex-direction: column;
     -ms-flex-direction: column;
     flex-direction: column;
     background-color: white;
     padding-top: 2rem;
 }
 
 #work .q-work-text {
     margin: 2rem 9rem 0 9rem;
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #448ccb;
 }
 
 #work .q-work-quflip {
     margin: 2rem 9rem 0 9rem;
     font-size: 1.2rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #898989;
 }
 
 #work .q-work-amaya {
     margin: 6rem 9rem 0 9rem;
     font-size: 1.2rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #898989;
 }
 
 #work .q-work-description {
     margin: 0.5rem 9rem 2rem 9rem;
     font-size: 1.1rem;
     color: #898989;
 }
 
 #work .q-quflip-image {
     width: 100%;
     height: 70rem;
 }
 
 #work .q-avaya-image {
     width: 100%;
     height: 50rem;
 }
 
 #work .q-work-zakoopi {
     margin: 6rem 9rem 0 9rem;
     font-size: 1.2rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #898989;
 }
 
 #work .q-zakoopi-image {
     width: 100%;
     height: 60rem;
 }
 
 #work .q-work-crewkarma {
     margin: 6rem 9rem 0 9rem;
     font-size: 1.2rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #898989;
 }
 
 #work .q-crewkarma-image {
     width: 100%;
     height: 70rem;
 }
 
 #work .q-logo-collection-text {
     margin: 6rem 9rem 2rem 13rem;
     font-size: 1.1rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #898989;
 }
 
 #work .q-logo-collection-images {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 0 5rem 0 5rem;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
     -webkit-flex-direction: row;
     -ms-flex-direction: row;
     flex-direction: row;
     -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     -webkit-box-pack: justify;
     -ms-flex-pack: justify;
     justify-content: space-between;
 }
 
 #work .q-logo-collection-images .q-images {
     margin: 0 5rem 4rem 5rem;
     width: 8rem;
     height: 5rem;
 }
 
 #work .q-portfolio {
     padding-bottom: 7rem;
     width: 100%;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-pack: center;
     -ms-flex-pack: center;
     justify-content: center;
 }
 
 #work .q-portfolio .q-portfolio-text {
     border-radius: 2rem;
     height: 4rem;
     width: 17rem;
     border: 0.17rem solid #ff363f;
     color: #ff363f;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-pack: center;
     -ms-flex-pack: center;
     font-weight: bold;
     justify-content: center;
     -webkit-box-align: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
     align-items: center;
 }
 
 #contact-us {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: black;
     position: relative;
 }
 
 #contact-us .contact-us-text {
     border-bottom: 0.3rem solid #ffba26;
     position: absolute;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 1.4rem;
     top: 4rem;
     left: 10rem;
     color: #ffffff;
 }
 
 #contact-us .q-email {
     position: absolute;
     color: #ffffff;
     top: 7.8rem;
     left: 10rem;
     font-size: 1rem;
 }
 
 #contact-us .q-contact-no {
     position: absolute;
     color: #ffffff;
     top: 9.6rem;
     left: 10rem;
     font-size: 1rem;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <script>
        // Picture element HTML5 shiv
        document.createElement("picture");
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/scottjehl/picturefill/3.0.2/dist/picturefill.js" async></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium Web" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../test/css/index.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
        <button class="cross">&#735;</button>
    </header>

    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <a href="#about-us">
                <li>ABOUT US</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#work">
                <li>WORK</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#contact-us">
                <li>CONTACT US</li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <picture>
                        <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="../test/images/slider_1_mob.jpg">
                        <img src="../test/images/slider1.png" alt="Los Angeles" style="
                    height:100vh;width:100vw;">
                    </picture>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <picture>
                        <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="../test/images/slider_2_mob.jpg">
                        <img src="../test/images/slider-2.png" alt="Chicago" style="
                    height:100vh;width:100vw;">
                    </picture>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <picture>
                        <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="../test/images/slider_3_mob.jpg">
                        <img src="../test/images/slider-3.png" alt="New york" style="
                    height:100vh;width:100vw;">
                    </picture>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="q-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="actve q-nav-about " id="is-visible" href="#about-us">ABOUT US</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="q-nav-work" href="#work">WORK</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="q-nav-contact" href="#contact-us">CONTACT US</a>
            </li>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="q-intro-text">
        <div class="q-mobile-app-text"><span class="q-text-header">MOBILE APP TEXT</span><br/>All the work and no play makes jack a dull boy!
            <br/> Join Libr8 cricket league. Unleash the <br/> sportsman in you</div>
    </div>

    <div id="about-us">
        <div class="q-about-us-layout">
            <div class="q-about-us-title"> ABOUT US </div>
            <div class="q-about-us-text"> We all are </div>
            <div class="q-about-us-images">
                <div id="q-image1">
                    <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/icons_pdt_dev.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
                    <div class="q-images-text"> PRODUCT </div>
                </div>
                <div id="q-image2">
                    <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/icons_clean_responsive.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
                    <div class="q-images-text"> CLEAN RESPONSIVE </div>

                </div>
                <div id="q-image3">
                    <img class="q-images" id="q-code" src="../test/images/icons_coding.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
                    <div class="q-images-text"> STATE OF THE ART CODING </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="q-team">
            <div class="q-team-text">THE TEAM </div>
            <div class="q-team-info">
                <div class="q-team-info-layout">
                    <img class="q-team-images" src="../test/images/jyoti.png" alt="Los Angeles">
                    <div class="q-team-member"> JYO </div>
                    <div style="color:#898989;">We all are 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="q-team-info-layout">
                    <img class="q-team-images" src="../test/images/hari.png" alt="Los Angeles">
                    <div class="q-team-member"> HAR </div>
                    <div style="color:#898989;">We all are a
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="q-team-info-layout">
                    <img class="q-team-images" src="../test/images/abhimanyu.png" alt="Los Angeles">
                    <div class="q-team-member"> MR </div>
                    <div style="color:#898989;">We all 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div id="work">
        <div class="q-work-text"> OUR WORK</div>
        <div class="q-work-quflip"> Quf </div>
        <div class="q-work-description">Lorem </div>
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="../test/images/proj_1_mob.jpg">
            <img class="q-quflip-image" src="../test/images/work1.jpg" />
        </picture>
        <div class="q-work-amaya"> Amaya 
        </div>
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="../test/images/proj_2_mob.jpg">
            <img class="q-avaya-image" src="../test/images/wrk2.jpg" />
        </picture>
        <div class="q-work-zakoopi"> Zakoopi  </div>
        <div class="q-work-description">Zakoopi 
        </div>
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="../test/images/proj_3_mob.jpg">
            <img class="q-zakoopi-image" src="../test/images/wrk3.jpg" />
        </picture>
        <div class="q-work-crewkarma"> Crewkarma  </div>
        <div class="q-work-description"> Crewkarma
        </div>
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="../test/images/proj_4_mob.jpg">
            <img class="q-crewkarma-image" src="../test/images/wrk4.jpg" />
        </picture>
        <div class="q-logo-collection-text"> Logo </div>
        <div class="q-logo-collection-images">
            <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/logos-02.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
            <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/logos-03.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
            <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/logos-04.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
            <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/logos-05.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
            <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/logos-06.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
            <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/logos-07.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
            <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/logos-08.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
            
        </div>
        <div class="q-portfolio">
            <a href="https://www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none;
                color:#ff363f">
                <div class="q-portfolio-text">
                    VIEW FULL PORTFOLIO</div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="contact-us">
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="../test/images/contact-us_mob.jpg">
            <img src="../test/images/contact-us.png" alt="Los Angeles" style="
                    height:30%;width:100%;">
        </picture>
        <div class="contact-us-text"> CONTACT US
        </div>
        <div class="q-email">Email : xyz@gmail.com</div>
        <div class="q-contact-no">Phone: +1 123456789</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".cross").hide();
            $(".menu").hide();
            $(".hamburger").click(function() {
                $(".menu").slideToggle("slow", function() {
                    $(".hamburger").hide();
                    $(".cross").show();
                });
            });

            $(".cross").click(function() {
                $(".menu").slideToggle("slow", function() {
                    $(".cross").hide();
                    $(".hamburger").show();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script src="../test/scripts/scrolling.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Now, what happens here is for `#about-us`  and `#work` ids , scroll is able to put css function inside my jquery to highlight active div with different color and border, but unfortunately, it does not happen for last div id `#contact-us`. What could be the reason for that? Is there any error in that code?

Comment: remove the extra </li> below contact-us link, here " <li><a class="q-nav-contact" href="#contact-us">CONTACT US</a>
            </li>
            </li>"  and check

Comment: I removed the extra tag, but it is not working

Comment: will you please edit your snippet?, it's not working either

Comment: @this.girish I have updated the entire snippet. Please do not run it in mobile  responsive mode.

Comment: @this.girish here you can clearly see that red line moves for about us and work , but it does not become active for contact us

Comment: The black "contact us" block covers up the navbar when it would be active.  If you remove the black background color you'll see your navbar scroll code is working just fine.

Comment: I did that, but contact us does not have red line beneath the text , just like aboutus and work text

Comment: Yes it does.  I posted an answer below to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some browsers, the black background in your "Contact us" section is covering up the navbar when that last link is active -- you can't see the red line because it's hidden behind the black background.

In other browsers the "contact us" section is short enough that it's not possible to scroll down far enough to trigger activating that last link. (`height:100%` doesn't work the way you'd think it should.)

Here I've removed the black background color and set its height to a bit more than the viewport height to guarantee that there's enough scroll room:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");
        $('a').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('actve');
        })
        $(this).addClass('actve');

        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 2
        }, 500, 'swing', function() {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            var scroll_start = 0;
            var startchange = $('.q-intro-text');
            var offset = startchange.offset();
            // $(document).scroll(function() {
            //     scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
            //     if (scroll_start > offset.top) {
            //         $('#q-nav').css('background-color', 'black');
            //     } else {
            //         $('#q-nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
            //     }
            // });
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event) {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#q-nav a').each(function() {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#q-nav ul li a').removeClass("actve");
            currLink.addClass("actve");
            $('.actve').css('color', '#4d4d4d');
            $('.actve').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #ff363f');
        } else {
            currLink.removeClass("actve");
            currLink.css('color', '#898989');
            currLink.css('border-bottom', '1px solid white');
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.container {
     padding: 0;
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
 }
 
 .menu {
     display: none;
 }
 
 header {
     display: none;
 }
 
 .carousel-indicators li.active {
     width: 1.3rem;
     height: 1.3rem;
     margin-right: 0.8rem;
 }
 
 .carousel-indicators li {
     width: 1.3rem;
     height: 1.3rem;
     margin-right: 0.8rem;
 }
 
 #myTopnav {
     display: none;
 }
 
 #myTopnav .q-hamburger {
     display: none;
 }
 
 #q-nav {
     width: 100%;
     height: 4rem;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     background-color: white;
     padding-top: 1.5rem;
 }
 
 #q-nav ul {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     justify-content: flex-end;
 }
 
 #q-nav .q-nav-about {
     position: relative;
     color: #898989;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 0rem 2rem 0 2rem;
 }
 
 #q-nav ul li {
     list-style: none;
 }
 
 #q-nav .q-nav-work {
     position: relative;
     color: #898989;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 0rem 2rem 0 2rem;
 }
 
 #q-nav .q-nav-contact {
     position: relative;       
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 0rem 8rem 0 2rem;
 }
 
 .q-intro-text {
     height: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0; 
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
     display: flex;
 }
 
 .q-intro-text .q-text-header {
     font-size: 2rem;
     font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 .q-intro-text .q-mobile-app-text {
     margin: 0 0 0 10rem;
     color: #ffffff;
 }
 
 #about-us {
     background-color: white;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout {
     height: 30rem;
     background-color: white;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
     padding-top: 2.5rem;
     text-align: center;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-title {
     margin-top: 1rem;
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #448ccb;
 }
 
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images {
     width: 100%;
     height: 50%;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image1 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     flex-direction: column;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image2 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     flex-direction: column;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image3 {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     flex-direction: column;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image1 .q-images-text {
     margin-top: 1rem;
     color: #898989;
     font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image2 .q-images-text {
     margin-top: 1rem;
     color: #898989;
     font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image3 .q-images-text {
     margin-top: 1.6rem;
     color: #898989;
     font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image1 .q-images {
     width: 30%;
     height: 30%;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image2 .q-images {
     width: 30%;
     height: 30%;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image3 .q-images {
     width: 30%;
     height: 30%;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-about-us-layout .q-about-us-images #q-image3 #q-code {
     width: 25%;
     height: 25%;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-team {
     height: 39rem;
     width: 100%;
     padding-top: 2rem;
     padding-bottom: 2rem;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
     -webkit-flex-direction: column;
     -ms-flex-direction: column;
     flex-direction: column;
     -webkit-box-align: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
     align-items: center;
     text-align: center;
     background: url("/test/images/ic_team.jpg") no-repeat;
     background-size: contain;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-team .q-team-text {
     font-size: 1.3rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-bottom: 2rem;
     color: white;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-team .q-team-info {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     padding: 0 8rem 3rem 8rem;
     -webkit-box-pack: center;
     -ms-flex-pack: center;
     justify-content: center;
     -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
     -webkit-flex-direction: row;
     -ms-flex-direction: row;
     flex-direction: row;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-team .q-team-info .q-team-info-layout {
     width: 33%;
     height: 100%;
     padding: 2rem 1rem 0 1rem;
     margin: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
     background-color: white;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-team .q-team-info .q-team-info-layout .q-team-images {
     width: 7.2rem;
     height: 7.8rem;
     padding-bottom: 1rem;
 }
 
 #about-us .q-team .q-team-info .q-team-info-layout .q-team-member {
     margin-top: 1rem;
     margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
     color: #ff363f;
 }
 
 #work {
     width: 100vw;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
     -webkit-flex-direction: column;
     -ms-flex-direction: column;
     flex-direction: column;
     background-color: white;
     padding-top: 2rem;
 }
 
 #work .q-work-text {
     margin: 2rem 9rem 0 9rem;
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #448ccb;
 }
 
 #work .q-work-quflip {
     margin: 2rem 9rem 0 9rem;
     font-size: 1.2rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #898989;
 }
 
 #work .q-work-amaya {
     margin: 6rem 9rem 0 9rem;
     font-size: 1.2rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #898989;
 }
 
 #work .q-work-description {
     margin: 0.5rem 9rem 2rem 9rem;
     font-size: 1.1rem;
     color: #898989;
 }
 
 #work .q-quflip-image {
     width: 100%;
     height: 70rem;
 }
 
 #work .q-avaya-image {
     width: 100%;
     height: 50rem;
 }
 
 #work .q-work-zakoopi {
     margin: 6rem 9rem 0 9rem;
     font-size: 1.2rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #898989;
 }
 
 #work .q-zakoopi-image {
     width: 100%;
     height: 60rem;
 }
 
 #work .q-work-crewkarma {
     margin: 6rem 9rem 0 9rem;
     font-size: 1.2rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #898989;
 }
 
 #work .q-crewkarma-image {
     width: 100%;
     height: 70rem;
 }
 
 #work .q-logo-collection-text {
     margin: 6rem 9rem 2rem 13rem;
     font-size: 1.1rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #898989;
 }
 
 #work .q-logo-collection-images {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 0 5rem 0 5rem;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
     -webkit-flex-direction: row;
     -ms-flex-direction: row;
     flex-direction: row;
     -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     -webkit-box-pack: justify;
     -ms-flex-pack: justify;
     justify-content: space-between;
 }
 
 #work .q-logo-collection-images .q-images {
     margin: 0 5rem 4rem 5rem;
     width: 8rem;
     height: 5rem;
 }
 
 #work .q-portfolio {
     padding-bottom: 7rem;
     width: 100%;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-pack: center;
     -ms-flex-pack: center;
     justify-content: center;
 }
 
 #work .q-portfolio .q-portfolio-text {
     border-radius: 2rem;
     height: 4rem;
     width: 17rem;
     border: 0.17rem solid #ff363f;
     color: #ff363f;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-box-pack: center;
     -ms-flex-pack: center;
     font-weight: bold;
     justify-content: center;
     -webkit-box-align: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
     align-items: center;
 }
 
 #contact-us {
     width: 100%;
     height: 125vh;
     position: relative;
 }
 
 #contact-us .contact-us-text {
     border-bottom: 0.3rem solid #ffba26;
     position: absolute;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 1.4rem;
     top: 4rem;
     left: 10rem;
     color: #ffffff;
 }
 
 #contact-us .q-email {
     position: absolute;
     color: #ffffff;
     top: 7.8rem;
     left: 10rem;
     font-size: 1rem;
 }
 
 #contact-us .q-contact-no {
     position: absolute;
     color: #ffffff;
     top: 9.6rem;
     left: 10rem;
     font-size: 1rem;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <script>
        // Picture element HTML5 shiv
        document.createElement("picture");
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/scottjehl/picturefill/3.0.2/dist/picturefill.js" async></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium Web" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../test/css/index.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
        <button class="cross">&#735;</button>
    </header>

    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <a href="#about-us">
                <li>ABOUT US</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#work">
                <li>WORK</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#contact-us">
                <li>CONTACT US</li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <picture>
                        <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="../test/images/slider_1_mob.jpg">
                        <img src="../test/images/slider1.png" alt="Los Angeles" style="
                    height:100vh;width:100vw;">
                    </picture>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <picture>
                        <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="../test/images/slider_2_mob.jpg">
                        <img src="../test/images/slider-2.png" alt="Chicago" style="
                    height:100vh;width:100vw;">
                    </picture>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <picture>
                        <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="../test/images/slider_3_mob.jpg">
                        <img src="../test/images/slider-3.png" alt="New york" style="
                    height:100vh;width:100vw;">
                    </picture>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="q-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="actve q-nav-about " id="is-visible" href="#about-us">ABOUT US</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="q-nav-work" href="#work">WORK</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="q-nav-contact" href="#contact-us">CONTACT US</a>
            </li>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="q-intro-text">
        <div class="q-mobile-app-text"><span class="q-text-header">MOBILE APP TEXT</span><br/>All the work and no play makes jack a dull boy!
            <br/> Join Libr8 cricket league. Unleash the <br/> sportsman in you</div>
    </div>

    <div id="about-us">
        <div class="q-about-us-layout">
            <div class="q-about-us-title"> ABOUT US </div>
            <div class="q-about-us-text"> We all are </div>
            <div class="q-about-us-images">
                <div id="q-image1">
                    <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/icons_pdt_dev.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
                    <div class="q-images-text"> PRODUCT </div>
                </div>
                <div id="q-image2">
                    <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/icons_clean_responsive.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
                    <div class="q-images-text"> CLEAN RESPONSIVE </div>

                </div>
                <div id="q-image3">
                    <img class="q-images" id="q-code" src="../test/images/icons_coding.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
                    <div class="q-images-text"> STATE OF THE ART CODING </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="q-team">
            <div class="q-team-text">THE TEAM </div>
            <div class="q-team-info">
                <div class="q-team-info-layout">
                    <img class="q-team-images" src="../test/images/jyoti.png" alt="Los Angeles">
                    <div class="q-team-member"> JYO </div>
                    <div style="color:#898989;">We all are 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="q-team-info-layout">
                    <img class="q-team-images" src="../test/images/hari.png" alt="Los Angeles">
                    <div class="q-team-member"> HAR </div>
                    <div style="color:#898989;">We all are a
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="q-team-info-layout">
                    <img class="q-team-images" src="../test/images/abhimanyu.png" alt="Los Angeles">
                    <div class="q-team-member"> MR </div>
                    <div style="color:#898989;">We all 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div id="work">
        <div class="q-work-text"> OUR WORK</div>
        <div class="q-work-quflip"> Quf </div>
        <div class="q-work-description">Lorem </div>
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="../test/images/proj_1_mob.jpg">
            <img class="q-quflip-image" src="../test/images/work1.jpg" />
        </picture>
        <div class="q-work-amaya"> Amaya 
        </div>
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="../test/images/proj_2_mob.jpg">
            <img class="q-avaya-image" src="../test/images/wrk2.jpg" />
        </picture>
        <div class="q-work-zakoopi"> Zakoopi  </div>
        <div class="q-work-description">Zakoopi 
        </div>
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="../test/images/proj_3_mob.jpg">
            <img class="q-zakoopi-image" src="../test/images/wrk3.jpg" />
        </picture>
        <div class="q-work-crewkarma"> Crewkarma  </div>
        <div class="q-work-description"> Crewkarma
        </div>
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="../test/images/proj_4_mob.jpg">
            <img class="q-crewkarma-image" src="../test/images/wrk4.jpg" />
        </picture>
        <div class="q-logo-collection-text"> Logo </div>
        <div class="q-logo-collection-images">
            <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/logos-02.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
            <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/logos-03.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
            <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/logos-04.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
            <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/logos-05.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
            <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/logos-06.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
            <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/logos-07.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
            <img class="q-images" src="../test/images/logos-08.svg" alt="slider" onerror="this.src='../test/images/slider1.png'">
            
        </div>
        <div class="q-portfolio">
            <a href="https://www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none;
                color:#ff363f">
                <div class="q-portfolio-text">
                    VIEW FULL PORTFOLIO</div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="contact-us">
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="../test/images/contact-us_mob.jpg">
            <img src="../test/images/contact-us.png" alt="Los Angeles" style="
                    height:30%;width:100%;">
        </picture>
        <div class="contact-us-text"> CONTACT US
        </div>
        <div class="q-email">Email : xyz@gmail.com</div>
        <div class="q-contact-no">Phone: +1 123456789</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".cross").hide();
            $(".menu").hide();
            $(".hamburger").click(function() {
                $(".menu").slideToggle("slow", function() {
                    $(".hamburger").hide();
                    $(".cross").show();
                });
            });

            $(".cross").click(function() {
                $(".menu").slideToggle("slow", function() {
                    $(".cross").hide();
                    $(".hamburger").show();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script src="../test/scripts/scrolling.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I ran your snippet. When I click about-us or work, it shows red line, but for contact-us , it does not show any line.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, man. I added a screenshot. Red line, right there.

Comment: Aaaah.  I just tried in Chrome; there the 'contact us' block is a different height than in safari, so it's not possible to scroll down far enough to trigger the red line on the "contact us" link; the document isn't tall enough.  Add some padding to the bottom of the document, perhaps.

Comment: @Mthaker I've updated the answer. Sorry, I didn't realize at first that it was a browser-specific problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
  document.addEventListener(
        'scroll',
        function( event ){      
            var $elm = $( event.target );  
           if(  $elm.scrollTop() + $elm.innerHeight() >= $elm[0].scrollHeight && elm.is( "your element" ) ) {               
                    //your code
           }  
   });
```

Comment: please describe what  this code does with  minimal example , don't just put a code write meaningful explanation too. Good luck

Comment: Where should I put these lines?

Comment: What is this intended to do?  `event.target` is always going to be the document, since it's caught by a document scroll event watcher, and the math in that if() doesn't make any sense as far as I can tell.